# How to extract single values from vector_float3

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

ARKit `ARFaceGeometry` class has a property

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) const vector_float3 *vertices NS_REFINED_FOR_SWIFT;
```

How can I extract single float values from vector_float3 type which contains 3 float values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `SCNVector3FromFloat3` in `SceneKitTypes.h`:

```
vector_float3 vertex = anchor.geometry.vertices[i];
SCNVector3 vector3 = SCNVector3FromFloat3(vertex);
float x = vector3.x;
```